# "The high resolution icon is absent" - realfavicongenerator

Tags: icons, favicon

I am getting a missing icon error for `Android Chrome` and for `Safari`.

[image]

This is the code i have included in the `head` and all the favicon icons are placed in the root.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/android-chrome-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="256x256" href="/android-chrome-256x256.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Here are the list of included icons

```
android-chrome-192x192
android-chrome-256x256
apple-touch-icon
browserconfig
favicon
favicon-16x16
favicon-32x32
mstile-150x150
safari-pinned-tab
site.webmanifest
```

Comment: RealFaviconGenerator's author speaking. Although you self-answered your question, I don't think checking all assets should have solved this. The regular favicon package created by RFG gives a full-green report. Maybe you submitted an image that was not big enough. When that occurs, RFG falls back on smaller icons because it doesn't upscale images. Maybe this is what happened the first time your created your favicon?

Comment: Yes that is true. I noticed recently.

Comment: Alright! In the end it's cool you got the job done!

Comment: I am sorry i know its old, but just want to clarify. What is the maximum size we need to avoid the errors.

Comment: You mean for the Android icon? The high resolution icon should be 512x512. And 180x180 for the Apple Touch icon.

Comment: I know its strange, if i select `Create all documented icons` i still get the Android error which i stated above. I have used 1000x1000 as a base icon.

Comment: How is your site manifest? Does it list all the expected icons? Are the icons present in the package? (ie. the Zip file you got from RealFaviconGenerator)

Comment: Yes all icons are included. I still get a warning.

Comment: I wan't trying to be rude, its just a suggestion. once the user uploaded their icons (you can mention the large resolution) and there is a simple button that says `generate icons with default option` and another button says `customize your options`. Once the icons are generated you can show how it looks on other devices with screenshots. And once the user is happy they can download the sets. You have a great site and the navigation is little confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I admit I have trouble taking hindsight with RFG as I worked on it a lot. So it's good to get fresh feedback. Well I can't undergo a UI refactoring at the moment but this definitely goes to my Someday/Maybe list.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue after going to the *Assets* tab and checked `Create all documented icons` and `Declare the icon in the HTML code` under *Legacy versions*

[image]